# I require assistance with the usage of glob()

Tags: php, glob

So, I'm trying to minimize the size of the bootstrap file (the core file), in this file I require many libraries and interfaces, I tried using the foreach(glob()) hack to lightweight it, however, my libraries' name are as follows: library.namehere.php, when I do foreach(glob()), I do it as follows:

```
 foreach(glob('library.*.php') as $Library) { require_once($Library); }
```

I also tried doing:

```
 foreach(glob('*.php') as $Library) { require_once($Library); }
```

And:

```
 foreach(glob('*.*.php') as $Library) { require_once($Library); }
```

And preforming other changes in hopes of getting it to work, but none seem to make it work, the result is just 'Array', and that's it.

Do you have any idea as to why this happens? What could be the cause? And what could possibly be the solution?

Comment: Works fine for me! Are you sure your librarys are in the same directory ?

Comment: Oh and, I also tried opendir() to open the directory then list the files inside of it, then closedir() after they're listed. However, that did not work as well, and the result was always just 'Array'.

Comment: Yes, @Rizier123. Hold on, do the files **need** to exist in the same directory?

Comment: They don't need to, but you have to write the directory in the glob pattern, like this: `glob('testDIR/library.*.php')`

Comment: I have done that, and it still just returns Array, I tried it now again and it didn't require them, the home page is killed and it returns the default error for a not found class. Does it help if I mention that I'm running LAMP, and using PHP5?

Comment: Do you include the file with glob into another one?

Comment: I can't say I understood what you asked, what you do mean?

Comment: Just try this: `glob(dirname(__FILE__) . '/YOUR_PATH_TO_THE_LIBRARYS_HERE/library.*.php' as $Library)` Also please show us the file structure where this file is located and where your librarys are located

Comment: Oh, I get it now. It's not that it doesn't work, I wasn't paying close attention to the error given, it's somehow loading the classes in alphabetic order (something I don't want, as it's loading child classes first before the parents), so since that's the case it returns an error of not found class.

Comment: Then use this:   `glob('library.*.php',  GLOB_NOSORT)` with this it takes the librarys like they are in the directory

Comment: That's still an issue, is it possible to list the files from bottom to top (last to first)? The child classes come first in the directory, the main parent begins with an S so it's at the last position in the directory.

Comment: Try: `foreach(array_reverse(glob('library.*.php', GLOB_NOSORT)) as $Library)`

Comment: Thank you for your assistance, I have got it to work after playing around with the code you've given me, I realized that since I was routing, every process went through the index file, and I was requiring the libraries directly as follows ('library/library.*.php') while in fact it should have been ('application/library/library.*.php'). Again, thank you for your assistance. :)

Comment: Accepted it. And sure, I will. Thank you! :)

Comment: This question requires assistance with an appropriate, helpful title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure to also include the path to the files in the glob call like this:

```
glob('testDIR/library.*.php')
```